# Mako Templating

Tags: python, mako

I am new to Python and Mako and such. My question might seem dumb, I apologise in advance but I looked at the docs and could not find it.

In .py files, I can use `#` character to take notes. I can also use

```
'''
notes
notes
'''
```

My questions:

- How can I do this with `.mako` files?
- What is the common name for this? (taking notes, annotating..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#comments

In almost all programming languges and related technical formats, this feature is called a comment.

Comment: Thank you. Is it always called as "Comments"? I couldn't find it when I looked for it with other names.

Comment: "Multi-line" comment is used most often I think